# php ajax autocomplete dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i made this autocomplete page .. i want when i click on the ajax result(email) a third ajax page display the username something like google when you start typing and select the the search u wanna make the result comes up

index.php

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/> 
</head> 
<body> 
<input type="text" name="search" id="live"/> <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Search"/> 
<div class="show"> 
<ul class="dropdown"> 

</ul> 

</div> 


<script> 
$( #live ).keyup(function(){ 


$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url: "ajax.php", 
data:{"search":$("#live").val()}, 
success: function(msg){ 
$(".dropdown").html(msg); 
} 
}); 



}); 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php 
$search=$_POST[ search ]; 
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","candy"); 
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE $search% "); 
if(!empty($search)){ 
$num=mysqli_num_rows($query); 
if($num != 0){ 

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 

echo "<li class= result >$row[email]</li>"; 
} 
} 
else{echo "NO search result found"; } 

} 

?>
```

result.php

i want it to display the username of the selected email

Answer (score 0):

use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event with dropdown lists like

```
// For dynamic Elements
$('.dropdown').on('click', 'li', function(){
    // Get the selected Email
    var email = $.trim($(this).text());

    // Send ajax request like you send before 
    // with email address and display result wherever required
    $.ajax({
        .........
    });
});
```

Comment: i have tried it and make the ajax send the request to third page result.php but i get undefined variable

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you send the username with the email as a hidden data? Something like this in your ajax.php:

```
echo "<li class='result' data-username='$row[username]'>$row[email]</li>";
```

With JQuery you will be able to get this username property:

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', '.result', function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('data-username') );
}
```